# Condition could not perform action

Tags: php

I make below condition but that is not meet. Condition could not perform action.
What is the solution ?

```
if(empty($_FILES["img"]["name"]))
```

Comment: Post your form and php code too for bettet understand your problem!!

Comment: and which action is not performing ?

Comment: Please give the rest of of your source so we can see what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure about the name of your File Input Element? Your Code implies that your File Input Element looks similar to this: **<input type="file"** ***name="img"*** **class="form-control" id="my_img" />**. Verify that the **name** attribute of your File-Input Element is **img**. Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if ($_FILES['img']['size'] != 0 && $_FILES['img']['error'] == 0)
{
// imag is not empty (and not an error)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `isset` in palace of `empty`

```
if(isset($_FILES["img"]["name"]))
```